# What should a trainer do when deadlifting straps fail?

Tags: deadlifts, exercise-equipment, grip

I have deadlifting straps that wrap around the bar to assist my overhand deadlifting grip.

Excluding hook grips, mixed grips, and working on increased grip strength, what is the next step up?  Are there different styles of grip-assisting tools like these straps that work better for higher weights?

I recall Eddie Hall's straps for the world record were figure-eight straps that went over his wrist on each end of the strap rather than relying on wrapped-strap friction against the bar.  Is that a better tool for high weights?

***Wrap-around straps***
[image]

***Figure-8 straps***
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Build grip strength or buy/make new wrist wraps.

Alternatively use Olympic grips 
[image]

If you want to build more grip strength, the best option is to stop gripping things. The fingers give incredible good levers for holding things, but the muscle moving the fingers is also a wrist flexor, to put it in a disadvantaged position use false grips when doing rows or pull ups.

[image]